# Fastest way to change head of a gzip file?

Tags: python, gzip

I maintain a benchmark library with gz-compressed files that contain descriptive metadata in the first few lines. By hand, I can decompress a 246MB gz-compressed file (using gunzip), change it, and compress it back (using gzip) in under 2 minutes using the linux terminal. On the same file, the following script takes almost 5 minutes to complete (using Python 2.7.5) and 12+ minutes (using Python 3.4.1) before I killed it.

```
import os, gzip, shutil

def renew_file(file, tempfile):
  f = gzip.open(file,'r')

  try:
    # Read and modify first line(s)
    buf = f.readline()
    buf = 'changing first line\n'

    # Write change to temporary file
    f2 = gzip.open(tempfile,'w')
    try:
      f2.write(buf)
      shutil.copyfileobj(f,f2)
    finally:
      f2.close()

  finally:
    f.close()

  # Overwrite file
  os.rename(tempfile, file)
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve higher performance?

Comment: Probably there are better solutions but you can try running the actual gzip && gunzip binaries in a subprocess.

Comment: don't store the metadata compressed... maybe a separate file? or an extra header?

Comment: What do you mean by "an extra header"?

Comment: Since the underlying zlib releases the GIL, there is benefit to doing this multithreaded - ditch copyfileobj and create a background thread to do the writes and use a queue to pass the data. In my experiment, the operation went from 77 seconds to 50.

Comment: @tdelaney It sounds like you have a working example. I would love to see this posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gzip on the command line [defaults to a compression level of 6](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip).  Python, however, [defaults to a compression level of 9](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open), which is slower but produces smaller files.  You can either pass `compresslevel=6` to `gzip.open()` if you want larger files sooner, or pass `-9` to `gzip` if you want smaller files later.

Comment: Made me facepalm at first, but passing gzip -9 to the terminal actually only adds 20s to the command line solution..

Comment: Hm... Well, I can tell you why Python 3.x is slower: It's Unicode decoding/encoding the entire file, while 2.x is just copying the bytes verbatim.

Comment: Adding compresslevel=6 to gzip.open() changed the execution time to just 1 minute..! So I guess your answer is correct, with the twist of a version-difference of gzip as command and embedded in Python.. Any trick for making Python 3.x as fast as Python 2.x?

Comment: @kevin - my python3 experiments were about as fast as python2... and gzip passed back `bytes`, not `str`, so it wasn't unicode encoding (which would be bad, considering that unicode encode/decode isn't guaranteed to be loss-less).